# How to make my android application launched in the boot and then hidden

Tags: java, android, android-service

I developed an android application that launch a backbone service at the `onCreate()`.

1) **In the device boot**, I want that my application start automatically and then **make its interface hidden** (not closed)

2) **In the usual usage**, If I open my application manyally (not in the boot), I do not want to make my application interface hidden.

Is it possible to fit these 2 requirements with Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the android service. and in the service `onStart()` method launch the service you want as a background task.

To launch the service in the boot of the android, use `BroadcastReceiver` class

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to show any UI (like splash screen) to user on every bootup? or you want to do any background operations?

Try using Boot Receiver(android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED) it will solve your both requirements

Thanks,
Jey.